# apply p.adjust function after group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My data `dat` is like this

```
set.seed(123)        
dat<- data.frame(
                comp = rep(1:4,2),
                grp = rep(c('A','B'), each=4),
                pval = runif(8, min=0, max=0.1) )
dat$pval[sample(nrow(dat), 1)] <- NA
```

pval column contains a list of p values from multiple ttest within each large group.
Now I need to apply the base r function p.adjust to adjust the p values within each group (A,B,...)
what I did was:

```
dat %>%
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    mutate(pval.adj = p.adjust (pval, method='BH'))
```

Below is the output of the above code:

```
comp grp  pval       pval.adj
1   A   0.02875775  0.08179538  
2   A   0.07883051  0.08830174  
3   A   0.04089769  0.08179538  
4   A   0.08830174  0.08830174  
1   B   NA  NA  
2   B   0.00455565  0.01366695  
3   B   0.05281055  0.07921582  
4   B   0.08924190  0.08924190
```

The result does not make sense. The last entry of each group,  pval and pval.adj are equal. Some pval.adj are much closer to pval than others.  I think something is wrong with applying the p.adjust function after group_by. It took me hours but could not figure out why... I appreciate if someone could help me with that.

below is the p.adjust function usage:

```
p.adjust(p, method = p.adjust.methods, n = length(p))
p.adjust.methods
# c("holm", "hochberg", "hommel", "bonferroni", "BH", "BY",
#   "fdr", "none")
```

Comment: Can you set a seed and run again? If we can get the same `pval` values you have, it would be easier to determine what the results should be.

Comment: Agree with the `set.seed`. I get the same results whether I run `p.adjust` in `dplyr` with a group by or if I pull a subset for one group out and run it by itself. It would also be good if you can explain **why** you "think something is wrong". It surprises me that I get the same value for two of the adjusted values in Group A (as do you), but this doesn't seem to have anything to do with `dplyr` or `group_by`. `p.adjust(c(0.0983715529320762, 0.0183719095773995, 0.0271179967094213, 
0.048782999929972), method = "BH")` gives the same result.

Comment: @Gregor   you are right. One of the pval and pval.adj are equal. I thought after adjustment, pval.adj should always be larger.... seems like my programming part is right

Answer (score 2):

@zesla your code is fine. Your confusion lies in the difference between `family-wise error rate` and `false discovery rate` which is what BH does.  With BH you are much more likely to see those equal values.

If you look at the doco for `p.adjust` and run the sample code:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(50, mean = c(rep(0, 25), rep(3, 25)))
p <- 2*pnorm(sort(-abs(x)))

round(p, 3)
round(p.adjust(p), 3)
round(p.adjust(p, "BH"), 3)
```

you'll see the same effect.  You can also run a traditional `family-wise error rate` adjustment like Holm to see the effect on your own data...

```
dat %>%
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(pval.adj = p.adjust (pval, method='holm'))
```

See also this [article](http://www.statisticshowto.com/benjamini-hochberg-procedure/) on how BH is calculated

Comment: Another vote for this answer. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with dplyr applying p.adjust to individual p values as one the answer suggest. Happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

you are calling p.adjust on each P value independently. I usually call p.adjust outside of the pipe for this reason.