# Adjusting the p-values on a subset of regression coefficients

Tags: r, dplyr

**Edited for Clarity**

I frequently do stratified analyses. However, to avoid spending Type I error on hypotheses tests
that aren't of interest, I would like to remove certain values before using `p.adjust()`.

```
library(purrr)
    library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
    library(broom)
    library(tidyr)
    
    mtcars_fit <- mtcars %>%
        group_by(cyl) %>%  # you can use "cyl" too, very flexible
        nest() %>%
        mutate(
            model = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)),
            coeff = map(model, tidy, conf.int = FALSE)
        ) %>%
        unnest(coeff) %>%
        select(-statistic)
    
    mtcars_fit
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl data               model  term        estimate std.error    p.value
#>   <dbl> <list>             <list> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   (Intercept)    28.4      4.18  0.00105   
#> 2     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   wt             -2.78     1.33  0.0918    
#> 3     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   (Intercept)    39.6      4.35  0.00000777
#> 4     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   wt             -5.65     1.85  0.0137    
#> 5     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   (Intercept)    23.9      3.01  0.00000405
#> 6     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   wt             -2.19     0.739 0.0118
    
    #If I want to adjust the p-values for multiple comparisons for the weight only and
    #save the Type I error as I don't want to test the intercept, I would do something like this
    mtcars_adjusted <- mtcars_fit %>%
        mutate(
            p.value2 = if_else(term != "(Intercept)", p.value, NA_real_),
            p.value_adj = if_else(term != "(Intercept)", p.adjust(p.value2, method = "fdr"), NA_real_),
            .after = "p.value"
        ) %>%
        select(-p.value2)
    
    mtcars_adjusted
#> # A tibble: 6 × 8
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl data               model  term        estimate std.error p.value p.val…¹
#>   <dbl> <list>             <list> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   (Intercept)    28.4      4.18  1.05e-3 NA     
#> 2     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   wt             -2.78     1.33  9.18e-2  0.0918
#> 3     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   (Intercept)    39.6      4.35  7.77e-6 NA     
#> 4     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   wt             -5.65     1.85  1.37e-2  0.0137
#> 5     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   (Intercept)    23.9      3.01  4.05e-6 NA     
#> 6     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   wt             -2.19     0.739 1.18e-2  0.0118
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​p.value_adj
```

As [this discussion on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212657/apply-p-adjust-function-after-group-by-in-dplyr)  indicates that dplyr and p.adjust() often don't work well together, I applied the function outside the pipe as suggested.

```
    #To check I will filter the dataset and make sure p adjusted values are the same
    p.adj <- mtcars_fit %>%
        filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
        mutate(p.value_adj = NA_real_)
    p.adj$p.value_adj = p.adjust(p.adj$p.value, method = "fdr")
    p.adj
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl data               model  term  estimate std.error p.value p.value_adj
#>   <dbl> <list>             <list> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   wt       -2.78     1.33   0.0918      0.0918
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   wt       -5.65     1.85   0.0137      0.0206
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   wt       -2.19     0.739  0.0118      0.0206
```

Created on 2022-08-18 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)

The result is that the adjusted p-values are different, so I am unsure what is correct. The fact that I adjusted the P-values in two different ways -- with objects `mtcars_adjusted` and `p.value_adj` -- and got different adjusted P-values is concerning. The adjusted P-values for each object:

```
mtcars_adjusted: 0.0918, 0.0137, 0.0118
p.adj: 0.0918, 0.0206, 0.0206.
```

The resulting dataset is that I want to keep the intercept estimates without adjusting them in the p-value. The resulting dataset would look something like `mtcars_adjusted`, but I want to make sure the p-values are adjusted accurately. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

## Implementing your adjustment within the pipe chain

You don't need to adjust your p-values outside of `mutate()` in your example. Below, I show the identical result can be produced within the piping chain.

```r
# Adjust p-values for "wt" parameter estimates using your approach
p.adj <- mtcars_fit %>%
filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
  mutate(p.value_adj = NA_real_)

p.adj$p.value_adj = p.adjust(p.adj$p.value, method = "fdr")

# Alternative approach
p.adj_alt <- mtcars_fit %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
  mutate(p.value_adj = p.adjust(p.adj$p.value, method = "fdr"))

# Show they are identical once ungrouped (which you should do once you are
# done with all by-group operations)
identical(ungroup(p.adj), p.adj_alt)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Whether you are accomplishing what you intended with your "outside of the pipe" approach is a different question than what you asked in your post, but I encourage you to make sure it is.

## Adding the intercepts

Once you have your adjusted estimates, you can add in the intercept rows by `filter()`ing them from the original object and passing them with your adjusted data to `bind_rows()`. You can also combine the two p-values columns into a single column if you'd like using `coalesce()`.

```r
# Get intercepts, bind into a single data.frame, and create a coalesced
# column that combined the (un)adjusted p-values
mtcars_fit %>%
  filter(term == "(Intercept)") %>%
  bind_rows(p.adj) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(p.value_combined = coalesce(p.value, p.value_adj))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 9
#>     cyl data               model  term   estim…¹ std.e…² p.value p.val…³ p.val…⁴
#>   <dbl> <list>             <list> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   (Inte…   28.4    4.18  1.05e-3 NA      1.05e-3
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   (Inte…   39.6    4.35  7.77e-6 NA      7.77e-6
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   (Inte…   23.9    3.01  4.05e-6 NA      4.05e-6
#> 4     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   wt       -2.78   1.33  9.18e-2  0.0918 9.18e-2
#> 5     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   wt       -5.65   1.85  1.37e-2  0.0206 1.37e-2
#> 6     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   wt       -2.19   0.739 1.18e-2  0.0206 1.18e-2
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​estimate, ²​std.error, ³​p.value_adj,
#> #   ⁴​p.value_combined
```

Comment: Thank you, @socialscientist. Part of the issue though is that I am not sure if the adjusted p-values are correct. Please see the above question for clarification.I  did it outside the chain per previous suggestions to ensure the accuracy of `p.adjust()`  Using `bind_rows()` to get to a full dataset is a good suggestion.

Comment: If the "outside of the chain" result is "correct" then reproducing the identical result *inside the chain* cannot be incorrect. If you do not know what you actually want the output to be because you do not know what it actually means to adjust a p-value, then that is not a programming question but is instead a statistics question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/. It seems like this is likely an XY question, so I'll leave it for others. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the question seems to be XY. The overall question is unclear and needs major edits. I am considering deleting the question and repost it with much greater clarity if you agree.

Comment: The question is not statistical in nature, I know I want to adjust FDR. It is more on what p-values from the chain that `p.adjust()` uses. The only reason I separated it was from research on the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212657/apply-p-adjust-function-after-group-by-in-dplyr